# Specific table querying role in Snowflake can't USE a warehouse

Tags: permissions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

I've created what I think is a very standard user with access to a single role that can query a single table:

```
create user new_user;
alter user new_user set password = 'some_pw';
create role new_role;
alter user new_user set default_warehouse = 'compute_wh';
alter user new_user set default_role = 'new_role';
grant role new_role to user new_user;
grant usage on warehouse compute_wh to role new_role;
grant usage on schema my_schema to new_role;
grant usage on database my_db to role new_role;
grant select on my_db.my_schema.my_table to role new_role;
GRANT OPERATE ON WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH TO ROLE new_role;
```

However, when I set this user up in a SQL client (like DBeaver), I can't run any queries:

```
USE WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH; -- fails even here
USE DATABASE my_db;
SELECT * FROM my_db.my_schema.my_table;
```

> SQL Error [2043] [02000]: SQL compilation error: Object does not
> exist, or operation cannot be performed.

What extra permissions could I be missing?

Comment: If you log in to the Snowflake WebUI as this user can you run those 3 statements? I think you also need to grant usage on the schema

Comment: @NickW is right ,  your user new_user need grant usage on schema too permission

Comment: You also need to grant the role to the user. Setting the default role does not grant the role to the user

Comment: The role has been granted to the user, and select has been granted on the schema. Still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: You need USAGE on the schema, rather than SELECT

Comment: @NickW I've added that and it unfortunately still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> USE WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH; -- fails even here

If user has access to warehouse but cannot use it, it may indicate it is suspended. I would add `operate` privilige:

```
GRANT OPERATE ON WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH TO ROLE NEW_ROLE;
```

and check if auto-resume is on or explicitly start warehouse:

```
ALTER WAREHOUSE IF EXISTS COMPUTE_WH RESUME IF SUSPENDED;
USE WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH;
```

---

EDIT:

To check current role the following code could be used:

```
SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();
```

If the role is different than anticiapted, it could be changed with:

```
USE ROLE COMPUTE_WH;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried that and it doesn't work either. I can run commands like "SHOW GRANTS" and "SHOW ROLES" but still can't run USE WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables `SHOW WAREHOUSES` does it show the warehouse on the list? Maybe `USE WAREHOUSE "COMPUTE_WH"`

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables But I would start from the simplest `SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();` and confirm you are using "NEW_ROLE". If it is different the first statent before `use warehouse` should be `use role new_role`

Comment: Oh that worked! Thanks @lukasz ! SELECT CURRENT_ROLE() was PUBLIC so after USE ROLE new_role everything works. Please could you modify your answer so I can accept it? I'm so relieved. How strange that it wasn't recognizing the default role.